# mysql distinct row or distinct field

Tags: mysql, distinct

Is there a performance or other difference between this:

```
SELECT distinct(users.id),2 as someFieldName ,0 as someOtherFieldName
From users join ...
```

and this:

```
SELECT distinct users.id ,2 as someFieldName ,0 as someOtherFieldName
From users join ...
```

result set is used as part of an insert statement and the select might return the same user i.d multiple time due to the join (not displayed here)

I am using mysql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as "distinct field".  Your first syntax is parsed identically to the second: the parentheses merely surround a field expression.  You could also write:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (users.id), (2) AS someFieldName, (0) AS someOtherFieldName
```

They are all equivalent.

If you want to avoid comparisons on your constant columns, you could instead use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT   users.id, 2 AS someFieldName, 0 AS someOtherFieldName
FROM     users JOIN ...
GROUP BY users.id
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference as `DISTINCT` in this context only operates on rows.

[From the SELECT docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)

> The ALL and DISTINCT options specify whether duplicate rows should be
>   returned. ALL (the default) specifies that all matching rows should be
>   returned, including duplicates. DISTINCT specifies removal of
>   duplicate rows from the result set. It is an error to specify both
>   options. DISTINCTROW is a synonym for DISTINCT.